# Calculated Column Greater than or equal to with nested if

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column

Can you please help with this formula.

```
=IF([Result2]<=3,"Low",IF(AND([Result2]>=4, [Result2]<=6),"Low Med",IF(AND([Result2]>=7,[Result2]<=12),"Medium",IF(AND([Result2]>=13, [Result2]<=16),"Med Hi",IF([Result2]>=16,"High","")))))
```

It works in excel however not in a calculated column in sharepoint online.

Cheers
Brett

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find any error in your formula!

```
=IF([Result2]<=3,"Low",
  IF(AND([Result2]>=4, [Result2]<=6),"Low Med",
    IF(AND([Result2]>=7,[Result2]<=12),"Medium",
      IF(AND([Result2]>=13, [Result2]<=16),"Med Hi",
       IF([Result2]>=16,"High",""
        )
       )
     )
   )
 )
```

**below are some points to check from your side**

- Make sure that the field name is correct
- Make sure that the field type is number without fractions
- Make sure that the field is supported in a calculated column

> Check this **[Supported and Unsupported Columns In SharePoint Calculated Column Formula](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/supported-fields-in-calculated-column-sharepoint/)**

- **Note:** the calculated column formula is only calculated or updated in the following cases:

  - Add New Item.
  - Update Existing item.
  - Update the calculated column itself in the List Setting.